# Is there a way to set plotly height depending on the table size?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

### I was trying to make a table with plotly, but the height is too big, and it became like this:

[image]

What I'm expecting is something like this:

[image]

and this is the code,

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

layout = dict(
    paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
)

header = ['LVL', 'Base ATK', 'ATK']
cells = [['1', '46', '10.8%'], ['10', '86', '14.7%'], ['20', '153', '19.1%'], ['30', '194', '23.4%'], ['40', '266', '27.8%'], ['50', '340', '32.2%'], ['60', '414', '36.5%'], ['70', '488', '40.9%'], ['80', '563', '45.3%'], ['90', '608', '49.6%']]

def format_list(items):
    level = []
    baseatk = []
    value = []
    for item in items:
        level.append(item[0])
        baseatk.append(item[1])
        value.append(item[2])
    return [level, baseatk, value]

fig = go.Figure(layout=layout, data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(
        values=header,
        line_color='black',
        fill_color='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        align='center'
    ),
    cells=dict(
        values=format_list(cells),
        line_color='black',
        fill_color='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        align='center',
        height=30),
    )
])

fig.update_layout(
    width=250, font=dict(color='black', size=12),
    margin={"l": 1, "r": 1, "t": 1, "b": 1}
)
```

As you can see, I already set the bottom margin to 0, and did not set the height size. Is there a way for it to automatically set the height depending on the table size, or without having to set the height value?

Comment: The normal top and bottom margins are minimized, so the graph will be closer to the top. You can also turn off autosizing in the layout settings; try `autosize=False`. You can also set automatic margins for the y-axis by deactivating cell height. `fig.update_yaxes(automargin=True)` Is there a reason you want to control the height, do you hate extra margins in notebook, or what?

Comment: @r-beginners I'm trying to only get the table without the transparent background, so when I export the fig, it will show me the table only like I mentioned in the 2nd image that's why i want to control the height.

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is only to make the cells smaller, I would change cells(dict(....height=30)) for 25, this value worked fine for me. Not sure if there is a way for autofitting based on the font size.

```
...
fig = go.Figure(layout=layout, data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(
        ...
    ),
    cells=dict(
        ...
        height=25),
    )
])
```

Ref: https://community.plotly.com/t/increasing-cell-height-in-tables/45329